Excel - How to create dynamic series in bubble graphs, based on column data?
I will need to create an Excel file with many bubble graphs to represent data. For each indicator:
Data will consist of columns: "City label", "Region" [will be the series I'm interested in], "Value" [X axis], and a "Y-delta" [identical for each region, to help place the data for the same region on the same horizontal line on my graph]
For visualization purposes, I will need to add one series per region (as each series will have one color), for each of the many graphs I have to do. Last time I did this and it matched the expectations. But how can I automate the series creation, so that I don't have to do N times the series selection?
Thanks a lot
What I tried:
I tried googling or videos and nothing seems to answer this problem.
I can still do it manually but it's longer.
Data example:



Index
KPI
Region
X
Y
Size




1
Number of people
Region_1
54%
2
1


2
Number of people
Region_1
19%
2
1


3
Number of people
Region_1
60%
2
1


4
Number of people
Region_1
47%
2
1


5
Number of people
Region_1
93%
2
1


6
Number of people
Region_1
61%
2
1


7
Number of people
Region_2
53%
1
1


8
Number of people
Region_2
47%
1
1


9
Number of people
Region_2
72%
1
1


10
Number of people
Region_2
100%
1
1


11
Number of people
Region_2
73%
1
1


12
Number of people
Region_2
38%
1
1


13
Number of people
Region_2
69%
1
1


14
Number of people
Region_3
59%
0
1


15
Number of people
Region_3
86%
0
1


16
Number of people
Region_3
44%
0
1


17
Number of people
Region_3
100%
0
1


18
Number of people
Region_3
36%
0
1


19
Number of people
Region_3
14%
0
1


20
Number of people
Region_3
4%
0
1


21
Number of people
Region_3
3%
0
1



I want to create series based on Region_1/2/3.

Can you add in some sample data in text format? Preferably in Table Markdown.
